# Javascript in adobe form field - converting a "Trade In Value" To Be Multiplied if falls within specified range

Tags: javascript, if-statement, range, adobe

Im attempting to create a Javascript range calculator for a "trade in value of a car" this is a small part of a huge project im working on, i have the finished version in an excel file but decided to remake in adobe acrobat pro using Javascript, the purpose is to adjust the value of a number if it falls between the ranges below, if someone can point me in the right direction to get this code to work, id really appreciate it!

```
In plain text below,

Trade Value X 2.00 If Less Than 5999.00;
Trade Value X 1.75 If Greater Than 5999.00 But Less Then 9000.00;
Trade Value X 1.50 if Greater Than 9000.00 But less Than 11,000.00;
Trade Value X 1.40 if Greater Than 11,000.00 But less Than 12,000.00;
Trade Value X 1.35 if Greater Than 12,000.00 But less Than 13,000.00;
Trade Value X 1.30 if Greater Than 13,000.00 But less Than 14,000.00;
Trade Value X 1.25 if Greater Than 14,000.00 But less Than 17,000.00;
Trade Value X 1.20 if Greater Than 17,000.00 But less Than 20,000.00;
Trade Value X 1.15 if Greater Than 20,000.00 But less Than 24,000.00;
Trade Value X 1.10 if Greater Than 24,000.00;
```

Should = “Amount Financed” Field In Adobe

The code im attempting to implement:

```
var VTV = Number(this.getField("VehicleTradeValue").valueAsString);
var AMF = Number(this.getField("AmountFinanced").valueAsString);
((VehicleTradeValue)*2.00) If (VehicleTradeValue) < 5999.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.75) If (VehicleTradeValue) < 5999.00 < 9000.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.50) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 9000.00 < 11,000.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.40) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 11,000.00 < 12,000.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.35) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 12,000.00 < 13,000.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.30) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 13,000.00 < 14,000.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.25) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 14,000.00 < 17,000.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.20) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 17,000.00 < 20,000.00;
elif:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.15) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 20,000.00 < 24,000.00;
else:
((VehicleTradeValue)*1.10) if (VehicleTradeValue) > 24,000.00;
    event.value = self;
```

Comment: What's this code? I see some JavaScript and some Python together?!

Comment: im still pretty new to coding, i dabble in java script but feel as if i know very little, currently in a boot camp in python and i know a little swift... i think im in over my head learning 3 different languages at the same time... basically im a novice in all 3...but all seem vary similar in the beginning, some of these advanced answers are very impressive. appreciate any help that can be offered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is the Answer Finally!!!

var vtv = this.getField("VehicleTradeValue").value;

```
if( vtv <= 6000) event.value = (vtv * 2.0);
else if ( vtv <= 9000) event.value = (vtv * 1.75);
else if( vtv <= 11000) event.value = (vtv * 1.50);
else if( vtv <= 12000) event.value = (vtv * 1.40);
else if( vtv <= 13000) event.value = (vtv * 1.35);
else if( vtv <= 14000) event.value = (vtv * 1.30);
else if( vtv <= 17000) event.value = (vtv * 1.25);
else if( vtv <= 20000) event.value = (vtv * 1.20);
else if( vtv <= 24000) event.value = (vtv * 1.15);
else ( vtv <= 200000) event.value = (vtv * 1.10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code would be like:

```js
function adjustVTV(val, separator = ',', every = 3){
  let vtv = +val.replace(/,/g, ''), n;
  if(vtv < 5999){
    vtv *= 2;
  }
  else if(vtv < 9000){
    vtv *= 1.75;
  }
  else if(vtv < 11000){
    vtv *= 1.5;
  }
  else if(vtv < 12000){
    vtv *= 1.4;
  }
  else if(vtv < 13000){
    vtv *= 1.35;
  }
  else if(vtv < 14000){
    vtv *= 1.3;
  }
  else if(vtv < 17000){
    vtv *= 1.25;
  }
  else if(vtv < 20000){
    vtv *= 1.2;
  }
  else if(vtv < 24000){
    vtv *= 1.15;
  }
  else{
    vtv *= 1.1;
  }
  vtv = vtv.toFixed(2).split('.'); n = vtv[0].split('');
  for(let i=n.length-every,z=0; i>z; i-=every){
    n.splice(i, 0, separator);
  }
  return n.join('')+'.'+vtv[1];
}
/* your use 
let vtv = +this.getField('VehicleTradeValue').valueAsString), amf = +this.getField('AmountFinanced').valueAsString;
console.log(adjustVTV(vtv));
*/
// example
console.log(adjustVTV('5998.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('8999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('10999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('11999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('12999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('13999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('16999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('19999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('23999.99'));
console.log(adjustVTV('24,000.00'));
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. You don't console things in the real world. That commented area would be put into your constructor or class that your `this` context belongs to. Of course, remove the comment markers and the`console.log`s. The `console.log`s are just there to show you the output.

Comment: sorry, was a little confused, i rewrote what im trying to do with a snapshot and deleted older posts to avoid confusion.